# How many group homomorphisms are there from $\Bbb Z_n \to \Bbb Z_m$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

In looking up this question, I found this site: [Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/number-of-group-homomorphisms-from.217416/).  In it, someone claims that $f(x) = kx$ is a homomorphism from the group $\mathbb{Z}_{m}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ if $m$ divides $kn$.  I assume this is all with the group operation being addition.  However, in the case of $m=10, n=15$ it seems that $k=2$ doesn't work.  I found that $f(1+9) = f(0) = 0\ne f(1) + f(9) = 2 + 18 = 2+3 = 5$.  Am I misunderstanding the claim or not computing something correctly?

Comment: The problem 7 here explains how we arrive at $f(x)=kx$ . You may want to see here - http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-llynch1/immerse/IMMERSEHW5SOLNS.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the claim. $f([x]) = [kx]$ is a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ if $m | kn$. You've got $n$ and $m$ switched in the claim, although not in your question title.

In your example, $f([x]_{15}) = [2x]_{10}$ is indeed well-defined and a group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{15} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ (not the other way around).