# True or false. Order of $\phi (a)$ is equal to the order of $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

If it's true write a proof. If it's false, give a counter example.

If $\phi : G_1 \rightarrow G_2$ is a homomorphism and $a\in G$ then the order of $\phi(a)$ then is equal to the order of $a$.

**My attempt**: This is false. Consider $\phi:Z_{15} \rightarrow Z_6$ difined by $\phi([a]_{15})$=$[a]_6$.

This is homomorphism since $\phi([a]_{15}+[b]_{15})= \phi([a+b]_{15})=[a+b]_6=[a]_6+[b_6]= \phi[a]_{15}+\phi[b]_{15}.$
Let $a\in Z_{15}=3$. The order of $3$ is $5$ since $3+3+3+3+3=0mod15$. The order of $\phi(3)$ is $2$ since $3+3=0mod6$.

EDIT: My counter example is not well-defined. What if i change it to $\phi([a]_{15}) = [3a]_6$ and follow the same steps?

Comment: Consider the trivial homomorphsim $\phi(a) = 1_{G_2}$

Comment: I would like to know if my counter example is correct.

Comment: @Dietrich: It is certainly not a duplicate, since it (implicitly) asks about a specific argument different from the one in the earlier question.

Comment: It is not clear what is your definition of $\phi$. Any homomorphism $Z_{15} \to Z_{6}$  can be decomposed as $Z_{15} \to Z_3 \to Z_{6}$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott But the discussion there about the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ is just too similar to the one given here; and anyway, the trivial homomorphism finishes it all.

Comment: Your argument seems incorrect to me : $15 \equiv 30 \pmod{15}$ but $15\equiv 3 \pmod 6$ and $30 \equiv 0 \pmod 6$ thsu your homomorphism isn't properly defined (it isn't a function) because you would have $\phi([0]_{15})=[3]_{6} = [0]_{6}$ which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Dietrich: No, it isn’t, and providing a correct argument does not answer the OP’s real question.

Comment: Can someone tell me what is the generalization of what I wrote, that any homomorphism $G_1 \to G_2$ can be decomposed as $G_1 \to H \to G_2$ ?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, if only the last part is the real question then the question should be edited (change the title and present only the real question).

Comment: @Dietrich: Someone who proposes a specific solution clearly wants feedback on that solution; it should not be necessary to make an explicit request.

Answer (score 2):

Your map isn’t well-defined: $[3]_{15}=[18]_{15}$, so $\varphi([3]_{15})$ should be equal to $\varphi([18]_{15})$, but in fact $[3]_6\ne[18]_6=[0]_6$.

HINT: Take $G_1$ to be any group with at least two elements and $G_2$ to be the trivial (one-element)group.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote down is not a homomorphism.
If it were then:
$$[0]_6=\varphi([0]_{15}) = \varphi([5]_{15} + [10]_{15}) = \varphi([5]_{15}) + \varphi([10]_{15}) = [5]_6 + [10]_6 = [3]_6.$$

Comment: Thank you. What if i change it to $\phi([a]_{15}) = [3a]_6$?

Comment: @combostudent: That doesn’t work either: $[1]_{15}=[16]_{15}$, but $[3]_6\ne[48]_6=[0]_6$, so this map also is not well-defined.

Comment: where are you getting $48 mod 6$ ?

Comment: @combostudent I think checking out this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976357/how-many-group-homomorphisms-are-there-from-bbb-z-n-to-bbb-z-m) will prove instructive.